# How do I share folders using key-based authentication on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, samba

I'm trying to share folders on Windows 10 so that they are accessible from Ubuntu machines in the same network. I got password-based authentication to work. But I'm not totally comfortable with using my login password for file sharing, and I wanted to disable password-based authentication and only use key files (similar how it's done in openssh servers). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with a simple setup (i.e no domain controller) and continue using windows shares, this is not possible.

Possible Workaround: Create a second user with a password on your computer. Prevent it from logging in locally, and grant it access to your shared folder. You can then use that users credentials to access the share.

To create a user without creating a folder for their files etc., use "Local Users and Groups" in "Computer Management" (`compmgmt.msc`). To then deny them local login, add them to "Deny log on locally" in the local security policy (`secpol.msc`) -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment.

You might find [this similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/323323/creating-a-windows-account-only-for-share-access) helpful, too.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but I had problems accessing my main user's home directory, even after adding the new user to `Administrators` group. I ended up having to explicitly give the new user permissions my home folder (and child directories). Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You should not use an Administrator user for this, but start out with a low-privilege user and only grant it permissions to the directories it needs. But I understand this does not make it easier.